# Minimum required API for using ActivityRecognitionApi via GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, activity-recognition

In order to recognise the user's physical activity (such as still, walking, running etc.), an app can use the [ActivityRecognitionAPI](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi) offered by Google.

I have successfully implemented and tested it on Nexus 6 with Android 5.1.1 version. Since my app would support the minimum sdk version of 14 (Android 4.0 version), I am wondering what is the minimum sdk version supported by the ActivityRecognitionAPI. I have already tried to read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient), but I could not find the answer to my problem.

After some research I found that ActivityRecognitionAPI uses GoogleApiClient for subscription, and GoogleApiClient relies on the Google Play Services. But now what is the minimum version of Google Play Services required to be available for supporting ActivityRecognitionAPI? Any help would be really appreciated and apologies if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Looks like that API is bundled as part of a library so the mininum sdk of 14 should be fine. You will need to check that a user has Google Play Services installed on their device though, some of the APIs will already do that. I would advise testing on devices that don't have Google Play services and on API level 14.

Comment: @riggaroo I have implemented the GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener that provides the ConnectionResult through onConnectionFailed method. This also tells the app if the Google Play Services is NOT installed on the device.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) page in the documentation the minimum API version is 9 for real devices and 17 for emulators, as only from this version on, the devices get the Google API updates:

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:
>
> - A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
> - The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.